# JQuery.getJSON('/rest') request http://computerName/rest instead of http://localhost/rest in dev server

Tags: jquery, ajax

`JQuery.getJSON('/rest')` request `http://mycomputerName/rest` instead of `http://localhost/rest` or `http://127.0.0.1/rest` when in local dev server, even though it requests the same destination but in second case the session will be different than previous one which lead to problem(I use java as backend).

How to fix this(use `http://127.0.0.1` as local host server address)?

Yes i can hard code it, but i don't want to change back and force when deliver it to server or switch to localhost.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way you just have to rely on one variable [which you can set based on your environment configuration]:

```
var basePath = "http://path.to/somewhere";

...

$.getJSON(basePath + '/rest').done(function(){ ... });
```

Comment: I think the problem is due to my computer config, however you solution just work.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC `$.getJSON()` uses `window.location.href`. So if you point your browser to `http://127.0.0.1/` instead of `http://mycomputerName/` you don't have to change anything.